# How to implement jQuery UI Touch Punch and Jquery-ui locally?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, npm-install, touch-event, jquery-ui-touch-punch

Accourding to this documentation ([jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/)) I tried to install the following packages with npm in order to implement them locally in my project:

1. jquery
2. jquery-ui
3. jquery UI Touch Punch

The first problem I had is, in the node_module folder of jquery-ui, jquery-ui.min.js is just not existing. Where can I find it?

The second problem is, when I use

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

in the head of my website, it`s not working, but

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

How could that be?

I hope someone can help me. It´s driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found an answer:

Instead of using `npm install jquery-ui`, you need to use `npm install jquery-ui-dist` (see [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/i-just-installed-jqery-ui-from-npm-and-there-is-no-jquery-ui-min-js-file-in-any-of-the-directories)) to get the missing jquery-ui.min.js and further essential files, which can then all be found under node_modules.

Subsequently, I implemented all three files from node_modules and it worked like a charme!

If someone has an answer to the second question, I still would appreciate it!